# First Person Camera controls

Tags: input, camera, xna, controls, monogame

I have recently started up a 3d first person shooter game in Monogame and I am having some issues with the camera controls, I am unable to figure out how I make the camera slowly turn on it's X axis when I hold down the left/right arrow keys.

At the minute, the code I have is as follows:

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(60, 20, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitZ);
        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 800f / 600f, 0.1f, 100f);
```

And then down in the update section I have this:

```
 if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(60, 20, 10), new Vector3(-2, -2, -2), Vector3.UnitZ);
            }
```

The issue is at the minute this code simply moves the camera to the side a little then stops. I am unsure on how to keep having it move until I let go of the key?

The entire of my code will be shown below incase I forgot something (the floor verts currently don't work and the names related to a ship is due to me working from a tutorial):

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Game1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Model model;
        Vector3 ship1Location = new Vector3(40, 0, 0);
        Vector3 ship2Location = new Vector3(20, 0, 0);

        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(60, 20, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitZ);
        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 800f / 600f, 0.1f, 100f);

        VertexPositionTexture[] floorVerts;
        BasicEffect effect;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            floorVerts = new VertexPositionTexture[6];
            floorVerts[0].Position = new Vector3(-20, -20, 0);
            floorVerts[1].Position = new Vector3(-20, 20, 0);
            floorVerts[2].Position = new Vector3(20, -20, 0);
            floorVerts[3].Position = floorVerts[1].Position;
            floorVerts[4].Position = new Vector3(20, 20, 0);
            floorVerts[5].Position = floorVerts[2].Position;

            effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            model = Content.Load<Model>("health2");

        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();




            Matrix ship1WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship1Location);
            Matrix ship2WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship2Location);

            if (IsCollision(model, ship1WorldMatrix, model, ship2WorldMatrix))
            {
                ship1Location = new Vector3(0, -20, 0);
            }
            KeyboardState kb = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                ship1Location += new Vector3(-0.1f, 0, 0);
            }

            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(60, 20, 10), new Vector3(-2, -2, -2), Vector3.UnitZ);
            }

            ship2Location += new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        private bool IsCollision(Model model1, Matrix world1, Model model2, Matrix world2)
        {
            for (int meshIndex1 = 0; meshIndex1 < model1.Meshes.Count; meshIndex1++)
            {
                BoundingSphere sphere1 = model1.Meshes[meshIndex1].BoundingSphere;
                sphere1 = sphere1.Transform(world1);

                for (int meshIndex2 = 0; meshIndex2 < model2.Meshes.Count; meshIndex2++)
                {
                    BoundingSphere sphere2 = model2.Meshes[meshIndex2].BoundingSphere;
                    sphere2 = sphere2.Transform(world2);

                    if (sphere1.Intersects(sphere2))
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            DrawGround();
            Matrix ship1WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship1Location);
            Matrix ship2WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship2Location);
            DrawModel(model, ship1WorldMatrix, view, projection);
            DrawModel(model, ship2WorldMatrix, view, projection);



            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        void DrawGround()
        {
            // The assignment of effect.View and effect.Projection
            // are nearly identical to the code in the Model drawing code.


            float aspectRatio =
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
            float fieldOfView = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MathHelper.PiOver4;
            float nearClipPlane = 1;
            float farClipPlane = 200;

            effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearClipPlane, farClipPlane);


            foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(
                    // We’ll be rendering two trinalges
                    PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                    // The array of verts that we want to render
                    floorVerts,
                    // The offset, which is 0 since we want to start 
                    // at the beginning of the floorVerts array
                    0,
                    // The number of triangles to draw
                    2);
            }
        }



        private void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(2f, 0, 0);
                    effect.World = world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;



                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the camera's position and the point it is looking at are necessary parameters to create a view matrix, you can simply rotate (think orbit) the LookAt `camLookAt` around the `camPosition` like this:

```
//declare class scope variables
Vector3 camPosition = new Vector3(60, 20, 10);//your starting camera position
Vector3 camLookAt = Vector3.Zero;//your starting camera focus point (look at)
Vector2 camUp = Vector3.Up;
float camYawRate = 0.004f;//set to taste


//in the Update method
float elapsed = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

//later in the method...
if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
      camLookAt = Vector3.Transform(camLookAt - camPosition,Matrix.CreateRotationY(-camYawRate * elapsedTime)) + camPosition;);//remove the - sign from camYawRate to rotate to the right (or vice versa)

      view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camPosition, camLookAt, camUp);
    }
```

And that's it, give it a shot. Add another similar block to rotate to the right.

Comment: I know this code is old, but can you please fix the end bit with `+camPosition;`? Where is it supposed to go, because you can't add a Vector3 to a Matrix directly.

Comment: It is written correctly. It is not adding camPositon to the matrix. It is adding it to the result of the Vector3.Transform method. It's like this: `Vector3.Transform(Vector3, Matrix) + camPosition`. The result of the Vector3.Transform is a Vector3. It is adding camPosition to that result. This bit of code causes the camera to rotate in place. In 3D, to rotate in place, you translate to object to the origin, rotate it a little, then translate it back to where it was. The +camPosition does that last translation back to its proper location. Hope this helps.

Comment: In my camera class, I have two floats `Yaw` and `Pitch`. I want to be able to have these in the class and when I want to move the camera, I add or remove to these two variables. In my `Update` method for my camera, I have these lines of code: `LookAt = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Backward - Position, Matrix.CreateRotationY(-Yaw)) + Position` and `LookAt = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Backward - Position, Matrix.CreateRotationX(-Pitch)) + Position`. With this code, I can only change pitch. How do I make it so I can move both at the same time?

Comment: Choosing to store your orientation as the two floats is the problem. In 3D, you should try to stay away from using angles to store overall yaw, pitch, & roll info from frame to frame. It becomes unnecessarily complicated to perform rotations about one axis without it affecting the other axis.  Use a matrix instead. then it's just combining last frame's matrix with another matrix built up this frame that represents a slight rotation or translation https://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/ 
Happy learning.